# Disaster Recovery Server in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos6, aws-sdk

We have a 3 Node Hadoop Cluster along with Two Ruby Servers that are live on AWS.

We need to create the DR Servers for the servers in AWS .

Can anyone suggest the best way to Create DR Servers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "best way" to design and implement a disaster recover plan will depend greatly on your recovery time and [recovery point objectives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recovery_point_objective):

> A recovery point objective, or “RPO”, is defined by business
>   continuity planning. It is the maximum targeted period in which data
>   might be lost from an IT service due to a major incident. The RPO
>   gives systems designers a limit to work to. For instance, if the RPO
>   is set to four hours, then in practice, off-site mirrored backups must
>   be continuously maintained – a daily off-site backup on tape will not
>   suffice. Care must be taken to avoid two common mistakes around the
>   use and definition of RPO. Firstly, business continuity staff use
>   business impact analysis to determine RPO for each service – RPO is
>   not determined by the existent backup regime. Secondly, when any level
>   of preparation of off-site data is required, rather than at the time
>   the backups are offsited, the period during which data is lost very
>   often starts near the time of the beginning of the work to prepare
>   backups which are eventually offsited.

AWS of course provides all the services you require to develop a [disaster recovery plan](https://aws.amazon.com/disaster-recovery/):

> Businesses are using the AWS cloud to enable faster disaster recovery
>   of their critical IT systems without incurring the infrastructure
>   expense of a second physical site. The AWS cloud supports many popular
>   disaster recovery (DR) architectures from “pilot light” environments
>   that are ready to scale up at a moment’s notice to “hot standby”
>   environments that enable rapid failover. With data centers in 12
>   regions around the world, AWS provides a set of cloud-based disaster
>   recovery services that enable rapid recovery of your IT infrastructure
>   and data.

Start by defining those values with management, consider costs of maintaining a disaster recover infrastructure, vs costs of downtime, then move to an analysis of the services offered by AWS to implement the plan:

- Placing services in multiple availability zones
- Backing up critical data sets to S3
- Running "warm" servers in other regions for recovery
- A written plan, and testing that plan quarterly